# Automatically name ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Just to start out, i am quite new to data science/analysis in r, so bear with me!
I have been playing around with the videogame sales (vgsales) dataset i got via datacamp and am doing some analysis on it while learning ggplot, dplyr and such.

I have created a plot that will randomly select a videogame and show me the sales of that videogame by region and platform as a barchart (see snip below). At the moment, the game selected ( "The Walking Dead: Season One" in this example) is printed in my console, but i would really like it to be placed on top of the graph. How can i change my code so the title of the randomly selected game is used as title to the plot? Of note, using ggtitle(paste(random_name(vgsales3)) will just put on a different random name which does not correspond to the data visualized.
[typical output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5wok.png)

The random game is selected by the following function:

```
random_name <- function(vgsales) {
    random_name <- sample(vgsales$Name, 1)
    print(random_name)
    }
```

the plot is generated by the following code:

```
ggplot(vgsales3 %>%
         filter(region != "Global_Sales",
                Name == random_name(vgsales3)),
       aes(Platform, value, fill = region)) +
      geom_col() +
      labs(y = "Sales")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some options to achieve your task:
To keep it near your approach we could do it like:

Here we use the example `mtcars` dataset and the name `selected_name` is passed to `ggplot`. The trick is to intermediate write to the console with `selected_game <- random_name(mtcars)` and the use in `ggplot`:

```
library(tidyverse)
random_name <- function(mtcars) {
  selected_name <- sample(mtcars$cyl, 1)
  print(selected_name)
  return(selected_name)
}

selected_game <- random_name(mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars %>%
         filter(am != 0,
                cyl == selected_game),
       aes(factor(gear), mpg, fill = hp)) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(y = "Sales") +
  ggtitle(selected_game)
```

[image]

Comment: Very usefull input!
I have incorporated your solution and wrote a new function that will both save the intermediary selected_name and run the ggplot code subsequently.